# Underscore and LEFT function

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have a column that has values that look like the following:

> 17_data...
>
> 18_data...
>
> 1801151...data

The data isn't the cleanest in this columns, so I am trying to use a LEFT function to identify the rows that have the 2017 year followed by an underscore `LEFT(column, 3) = '17[_]'`  This doesn't return a single column.  So to troubleshoot, I added this WHERE clause to the SELECT statement to see what was getting returned, and I got the value 175 where the actual first three characters are "17_".

Why is this, and how can I structure my WHERE clause to pick up those rows?

Comment: Try LEFT(column, 3) = '17/_'    the escape character makes SQL treat whatever follows it as a literal character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you tried adding 'where' with a rule of `LEFT(column, 3) = '17[_]'`, it was doomed to fail. Operator '=' performs exact comparison: both sides must be equal. That is, it would look for rows whose first 3 characters (left,3) are equal to `17[_]`, that is, 5 characters, one, seven, bracket, underscore, bracket. Text of 3 characters will not exactly-match 5 characters, ever.

You should have written simply:

```
WHERE  LEFT(column, 3) = '17_'
```

I guess that you've got the idea for adding a bracket from reading about LIKE patterns. LIKE operator allows you to look for strings contained at start/end/middle of the data.

```
WHERE column LIKE 'mom%'    - starts with mom
WHERE column LIKE '%dad'    - ends with dad
```

and so on. LIKE supports '%' meaning "and then text of any length", and also "_" meaning "and then just one character". This forms a problem: when you want to say "starts with _mom", you cannot write

```
WHERE column LIKE '_mom%'
```

because it would also match 9mom, Bmom, and so on, due to `_` meaning 'any single character'. That's why in such cases, only in LIKE, you have to write the underscore in brackets:

```
WHERE column LIKE '[_]mom%'      - starts with _mom
```

Knowing that, it's obvious that you could construct your 'starts with 17_' with LIKE as well:

```
SELECT column1, column2, ..., columnN
FROM sometable
WHERE column LIKE '17[_]%'
```

Comment: When I put LEFT(column, 3) into the SELECT statement, instead of returning '17_', it actually returns 175.  Any idea why that is?

Comment: @mschmidt you probably have MANY rows in that table that start with 17, some probably start with 17_ while others start with 175 etc. If you wrote just `like 17_` or `like 17%` or not have such `where col like..` phrase at all, then you will grab all rows, not just those you wanted. Make sure you've set the `where` filter properly. Try out queries like: `select LEFT(col, 3), col from table where col like '17%'` and `select LEFT(col, 3), col from table where col like '17[_]%'`. They return 2 cols so you can compare what LEFT produces, what was the original col value, and how WHERE filtered it.

Comment: That is exactly what I did; I eliminated everything from the WHERE clause, and just had two columns: the LEFT function on my column, and an unaltered main column.  What was odd was seeing the LEFT function return 175 while the actual data was 17_15116.  I'm trying to understand why the LEFT function would return 175 when it should return 17_  .

Comment: @mschmidt: *that* is odd. If you don't have any silly hard-to-notice typo, I would consider it a bug in mssql2012. I'm not sure if they still accept bug reports for that version.. You could paste here the whole query and maybe some real rows as example.. maybe someone will notice a thing we've not discussed yet